# InfoPath Repeating Tables: Force all rows to have same value for one column

Tags: infopath, repeat

Does anyone know a way to have all the rows of one column of a repeating table to always have the same value?

Say the user changes the value in the first row for that column, then all the other cells in that column change to have the new value. (Preferably this will happen if a user changes any cell in the column, not just the one in the first row, but just the first row would be fine if that's all that's possible).

I have access to both InfoPath 2007 and InfoPath 2010 so can use either. The form submits data to and receives data from an SQL Server database. Code is fine if this requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to change the field from a repeating field to just multiple copies of the same field (since you want it to always be the same there is no point in storing multiple versions).

On the data source tab, all the fields that you put in the repeating section are in a group folder with the little repeating icon on it. Right click on the field you want to be non repeating and choose move. Put it anywhere outside the repeating group folder (the encompassing folder is usually a good choice but it can be anywhere). The field on the design surface will now show a little info box that says "this item can't be repeated" (or similar).

Now you just have multiple copies of the same field - so if you change any one of them they will all update to reflect the value.

Comment: +1 great answer! i haven't tried this; was actually going to suggest that code behind was the only way to do it, but this is a way better solution ;-)